# Finding several circles new cx, cy after translation

Tags: d3.js

So I've got two circles, sustainableCircle and one being referenced currently by `this`. I'm applying transformations to both of the circles, like so:

```
    d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.select(this).attr("originX") + "," + d3.select(this).attr("originY") + ")scale(" + scaler + ")translate(" + -d3.select(this).attr("cx") + "," + -d3.select(this).attr("cy") + ")")
    .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scaler + "px");

    sustainableCircle.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + -.6*sustainableCircle.attr("cx") + "," + -.6*sustainableCircle.attr("cy") + ")scale(" + .3*scaler + ")")
```

Now I'm trying to create a line that begins at `this` circle's center point, and ends at `sustainableCircle`'s centerpoint. Obviously, because we've done a translation, the following code does not work:

```
      var newCLine = svg.append("line").attr({
        x1: d3.select(currentCircle).attr("cx"),
        y1: d3.select(currentCircle).attr("cy"),
        x2: sustainableCircle.attr("cx"),
        y2: sustainableCircle.attr("cy"),
        opacity: 1,
        stroke: "black"
      });
```

What do I need to do to access the new `cx` and `cy` positions of my circles? For reference, I'm using d3 v3.5.17

Comment: why not just get  d3.select(currentCircle).attr("originX") and same for y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against setting setting `cx`/`cy` attributes and then `translating` the circle as well.  Just use one method of setting positions to simplify your life down the road.

That said, the position you are looking for should just be:

```
var cc = d3.select(currentCircle),
    cc_trans = d3.transform(cc.attr("transform")),
    cc_x = +cc.attr('cx') + trans.translate[0],
    cc_y = +cc.attr('cy') + trans.translate[1],
    sc_trans = d3.transform(sustainableCircle.attr("transform")),
    sc_x = +sustainableCircle.attr('cx') + sc_trans.translate[0],
    sc_y = +sustainableCircle.attr('cy') + sc_trans.translate[1];

var newCLine = svg.append("line").attr({
    x1: cc_x,
    y1: cc_y,
    x2: sc_x,
    y2: sc_y,
    opacity: 1,
    stroke: "black"
  });
```

Comment: Mark -- you are right on the money with your first sentence. I've completely gotten rid of translations and am now modifying the individual circles. THANK YOU!